# How to specify only enabled dates in daterangepicker.js?

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

As you can see I have already disabled the past days and weekends. I want to know how to enabled only specified dates.

[image: daterangepicker.js]

```
$('#leave').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    },
    minDate: moment(),
    isInvalidDate: (date) => {
        return (date.day() == 0 || date.day() == 6);
    }
});
```

Comment: `date.day() === 0 || date.day() === 6 || validDates.find(validDate => validDate == date) === null)`

Comment: @Andreas `validDates is not defined`. I'm not really good at javascript.